# File Sharing application members-to-members

Tags: php, web, sharing, file-sharing

guys

Do you know any available PHP third party application or script which allows all my registered members to share their files to other members?

I'm thinking similar with this one (My concern on that are there is no support doc and it seems the author of the script is gone for a long time.)
http://codecanyon.net/item/really-simple-file-sharing-web-application/51228

Really appreciated to your help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Opendocman](http://www.opendocman.com/) checkout this open source application. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I will check that :)
I'm looking for something that a member can upload a file then it generates a code (download link) that they will send to the recipient.